# rails and ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I have started to learn rails and javascript.
How i canmake properly ajax request to rails controller with jquery?
I write in js file

```
$.get('http://localhost:3000/take/show',{},function(s){
           alert(s);
          },'text');
```

in controller:

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
  def show 
    render :json => "Hi!"
  end
end
```

but instead i see only blank alert dialog. What i have done wrong? In all tutorials i see thatthe URL in $.get should be like this "take/show" but it would not work in my case, so why?

Comment: What does your URL normally show when you visit it?

Comment: Isn't the URL resolved by controller name (as long as you don't change it in the routes file)? So your Controller should be named take or the URL changed to first/show.
Also you can just omit the second argument in jQuery.get if you don't have any params

Comment: my url show me "Hi" in my browser

Comment: Use 'rake routes' to see what you should use as an url